# How to fetch data from different rows into a php array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I’m working on a php page and I want to display usernames according to a parameter that we’ll call `h`. So basically, I want to take all the ids from an sql database where `h="x"` but when I use my code only the first row gets fetched to the array:

```
$query = "Select id from $usertable where hschool='$hschool'";
$Mquery = mysql_query($counting);
$Array = mysql_fetch_array($counting);
```

I’ll appreciate all the help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through it to retreive all the data:

```
    $query = "Select id from $usertable where hschool='$hschool'";
    $Mquery = mysql_query($counting);
    $ids = Array();
    while( $Array = mysql_fetch_array($Mquery)) {
        // $Array will contain 1 row
        $ids[] = $Array['id'];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this does return the values but how can I make them to be so ? Array[0] => ID 1 Array[1] => ID 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
   try this php code:

    <?php



         $Mquery = mysql_query("Select * from $usertable where hschool='$hschool'");

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Mquery))
               {
                  echo row[id];//This will display all the row id's.
               }

    ?>
```

Here row[*place column name here*] place the column name inside the row[] which will give you the column value for all the rows.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($Array = mysql_fetch_array($Mquery)){
  echo $Array['f'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array() returns one row at a time. So you will have to do something like,

```
while($Array = mysql_fetch_array($Mquery)){
    //Use $Array here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

we cannot call the spacefic id because it return one row or duplication of the raw

```
$query = "Select * from username ";
$Mquery = mysql_query($query);
while( $Array = mysql_fetch_array($Mquery)) {
    // $Array will contain number of row
}
```